# Channel form not submitting

Tags: safecracker, ssl

I have an issue with submitting on my channel form , the form doesn't work under https but it is ok under http. Its a form to edit user profiles.

I have added secure_action="yes" secure_return="yes" to the channel form tag but to no avail. Note my form is stashed and its called as an stash embed which my the cause of my issue .
Also currently I only have https on the user profile editing part of the site

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please clarify.. is this a channel entry form, or a member profile form? It sounds like you mean a member profile form, unless you are using something like Zoo Visitor. Please give an example tag you're using to generate your form, and the form URI as well as the return path URI for this form. Also, post your relevant .htaccess lines related to forcing SSL only on the profile editing part (why aren't you using SSL everywhere???)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it had to do with config path on my dev server , when applied to my production site it works ok. I have decided to apply https to the whole site too,